# New variable calculation with input from multple groups in long format

Tags: r, dplyr, long-format-data

I was wondering whether the following calculation is possible using `dplyr` without transforming my data into wide format. My data looks like the following:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1:2, 6)),
                   Date = c(rep(as.Date('2022-03-01'), 4), rep(as.Date('2022-03-02'), 4), rep(as.Date('2022-03-03'), 4)),
                   Type = rep(LETTERS[c(1,1,2,2)], 3),
                   Value = c(1,2,101,102,3,4,103,104,5,6,105,106))
```

My goal is to make a calculation, which involves the value of a certain day from type B, but as well the value from the previous day of type A **AND** type B. If the calculation would only be within one group, then `dplyr::lag` is the way to go. But I do not see the way in this case. I'd like to avoid pivoting my data into wide format.

So as an example, I'd like to calculate X = B(t) - A(t-1) * B(t-1), where t is denoting the date. My goal in this case would be something like the following dataframe:

```
data_goal <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1:2, 3)),
                        Date = c(rep(as.Date('2022-03-01'), 2), rep(as.Date('2022-03-02'), 2), rep(as.Date('2022-03-03'), 2)),
                        X = c(NA, NA, 103 - 1 * 101, 104 - 2 * 102, 105 - 3 * 103, 106 - 6 * 104))
```

If I would calculate the daily difference for each type on its own, my solution would be

```
data |>
  dplyr::arrange(Date) |>
  dplyr::group_by(ID, Type) |>
  dplyr::mutate(Diff = Value - dplyr::lag(Value, n = 1))
```

But unfortunately I have no idea how I might extend this.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Note that I am also glad to know, if this is not possible. Then I would move on to transforming the table into wide format and continue from there. My actual data has a lot more types, which is why I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be useful

```r
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep(1:2, 6)),
  Date = c(rep(as.Date('2022-03-01'), 4), rep(as.Date('2022-03-02'), 4), rep(as.Date('2022-03-03'), 4)),
  Type = rep(LETTERS[c(1, 1, 2, 2)], 3),
  Value = c(1, 2, 101, 102, 3, 4, 103, 104, 5, 6, 105, 106)
)

library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(grp = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(Diff = map(.x = seq(max(grp)),
                       .f = ~ Value[Type == "B" &
                                      grp == .x] - Value[Type == "A" &
                                                           grp == .x - 1] * Value[Type == "B" &
                                                                                    grp == .x - 1])) %>%
  unnest(Diff) %>%
  add_case(Diff = rep(NA, length(unique(data$ID))), .before = 1) %>%
  add_column(distinct(data, ID, Date), .before = 1)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      ID Date        Diff
#>   <int> <date>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 2022-03-01    NA
#> 2     2 2022-03-01    NA
#> 3     1 2022-03-02     2
#> 4     2 2022-03-02  -100
#> 5     1 2022-03-03  -204
#> 6     2 2022-03-03  -310
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, in the end I opted for pivoting wider, but your solution solved the question. So take my upvote!